# Statistics - % of population

Tags: statistics

I have a question for the experts. In my course of work I'm required to calculate a metric, hypothetically let's call it the High Earners % - defined as the % of a population that earns at least 25% more than the population's average annual salary. Easy enough in itself.

Now there is a certain group within the population that skews the data because of the nature of their industry, again as an example they could be your Wall Street investment bankers etc. What I want to know is the % of a population that are high earners sans this subgroup, as this would in theory give a more accurate representation of the data. Let's call this metric High Earners (excluding Subgroup) %.

My issue is my boss and I disagree on how the High Earners (excluding Subgroup) % should be derived. My take is by excluding this subgroup from the total population, the denominator (total population) and population average are changed and hence so is the numerator (people earning at least 25% more than population average). He is adamant that total population and population average should remain constant while only the numerator changes.

Logically I know I'm probably right but given its been 15 years since graduation, I can't seem to find the right way to explain this properly to him. Would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, maybe try to reformulate with your boss using symbols?

You have a population of $N$ individuals and suppose the average salary is $s$.

You also have a sub-population of $M$ individuals, whose salary is higher than a certain threshold $\tau$.

Then you have the population of "normal-earners", consisting of those $N-M$ individuals from the original population who earn less than $\tau$ and in average the salary of these people is $s^\prime$ (in general lower than $s$).

Then your percentage of high-earners is:
$$\frac{\#\{\text{annual salary between }1.25s^\prime\ \text{ and }\tau\}}{\#\{\text{annual salary less than }\tau\}=N-M}$$

If you follow your boss, you end up with

$$\frac{\#\{\text{annual salary between }1.25s\ \text{ and }\tau\}}{N}$$

which is a perfectly valid quantity but maybe does not deserve the name "high earners", since in the original population of $N$ people there is a chunk of people earning more than them.

For example, the last number can be very low if the salary of the "very-high-earners" makes $s$ rather close to $\tau$. Some actual examples combined with common sense should show that this is not the correct approach.